# Content Security Policy is not running .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, security

I want to use Content-Security-Policy and tried to add in my .htaccess.

**Problem:** I checked with an chrome plugin is the CSP is running but dont find.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' *.facebook.com;frame-ancestors 'self' *.facebook.com;script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-rAnd0m123' 'unsafe-inline' http: https:;base-uri 'none';object-src 'none';"
</IfModule>


###DEFLATE### 
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
          ExpiresActive on

          ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 60 days"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that PHP set the header self, thats mean its ignore the .htaccess setting.

I had to set the CSP with PHP:

```
header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' *.facebook.com;frame-ancestors 'self' *.facebook.com;script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-rAnd0m123' 'unsafe-inline' http: https:;base-uri 'none';object-src 'none'");
```